# Getting home in parcheesi

Tags: parcheesi

If I am on the home path and need a 3 to get into home, can I get in if I roll double 3's? This was my last pawn. We weren't sure if I was the winner or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (in most rules; check your specific rules for exceptions). From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi#Rules)

> Pieces may only be moved to the home position with an exact application of the total roll, **the value on a single die**, or the complete application of a reward.

You cannot voluntarily forfeit a roll, but you can take part of the roll if that is your only option.

> All die rolls must be taken and may not be voluntarily forfeited by a player.

> If either of two rolls must be forfeited, the player must forfeit the lower number.

Comment: Thank you. We were not sure because I rolled double 3's. Thank you for helping to clear it up.

Comment: @AnthonySchoentube : you're welcome. And welcome to the site. To accept an answer, mark it as "accepted".